# HTML inputs overlapping when using absolute positioning

Tags: html, css, forms

I'm trying to create an input form on a web page, and I want all of the input elements to be lined up along a certain column. My idea was to use absolute positioning to just shift all of the input elements over to a specific point on the page. It's working fine, except for one problem: the input elements are overlapping with each other a little bit, vertically.

Here's a MVCE:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head>
<style>
span.right_align {
    display: inline;
    position: absolute;
    left: 80px;
}
div.form_container {
    position: relative;
}
</style>
<title>World's Best GUI</title></head>

<body type="text/css" style="background-color: #F7D879; font-family: Georgia, serif">

<div class="form_container">
  <form name="guiForm" method="post" action="return false;">
    Input 1: <span class="right_align"><input type="text"></span><br>
    Input 2: <span class="right_align"><select autocomplete="off">
    <option value="yes">Yes</option>
    <option value="no">No</option></select></span><br>
    Input 3: <span class="right_align"><input type="text" size="50"></span><br>
    Input 4: <span class="right_align"><input type="text"></span>
  </form>
 </div>

</body>
</html>
```

As far as I can tell, the problem is because the font is smaller than the size of the input box, but it's the size of the font that determines where a new line "begins". If you comment out or remove everything in the `right_align` class, they stop overlapping (but they also stop lining up so nicely).

I'll also note that the reason I went for the span-class solution is because I need to 1) have some lines dynamically disappear and reappear, depending on the current state of a drop-down, and 2) dynamically create new input items that will also line themselves up nicely. This seemed like a solution that would interfere very little with the current workings of my web page.

Is there a simple way to fix this? Should I be creating these columns in an entirely different way? I'm open to totally new ideas as well.

EDIT: someone suggested I create a jsfiddle, so I did: http://jsfiddle.net/uy9comxk/

EDIT 2: there will be lines where I have multiple inputs that have to appear beside each other on the same line (for date inputs). I didn't include them because it would have increased the MCVE size by a lot.

Comment: @User thanks for the suggestion, I added it to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your css, use a `line-height` and it will work:

```
div.form_container {
    position: relative;
    line-height: 25px;
}
```

[With a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mhtkns43/1/)

Comment: 22px does pretty much exactly what I was hoping for. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using a form, you should use the label tag and set the width of each - ideally a little longer than than width of the inputs' names to account for longer ones. Using the label for the inputs will also fix the overlapping issue of the inputs.

CSS:

```
label {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 80px;
}
input {
    margin-left:10px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<form name="guiForm" method="post" action="return false;">
  <label for="input1">Input 1:</label> <input name="input1" type="text"><br>
  <label for="input2">Input 2:</label> <input name="input2" type="text"><br>
  <label for="input3">Input 3:</label> <input name="input3" type="text"><br>
  <label for="input4">Input 4:</label> <input name="input4" type="text"><br>
  <label for="input5">Input 5:</label> <input name="input5" type="text"><br>
</form>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ub3bw1rv/

Comment: This is an interesting solution, but there are several points in the form where I have multiple drop down inputs on the same line (for date inputs). Will this solution still work? It fails when I try it in the fiddle you provided, as the inputs have a gap between them.